# Add app to page tab dialog - How to get the ids of the pages where the tab was added in return?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I have to display different content for different pages using my app in a page tab.

I want to allow the user to add my app using the [Add app to page dialog.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/)

The problem is i have to get the page ids to know where the page tab app was added to.

If this is not possible: What are the best practices for providing a easy way to serve custom content to different pages in their page tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **signed_request** is passed to all *Page Tabs* and contains the page id, as well as the user's admin status and whether the user has liked that page. This information is available even if the user has not authorized the app.

Comment: Yes that I know. But somehow i need to know which page belongs to which custom page(user account in my system) and for that i need to get to know the page id when adding the app to the page.

Comment: To add an app to a page, use a the add tab dialog. When the user clicks add Facebook returns the page id's of all pages to which the app was added.

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8573603/redirect-to-page-with-add-page-tab-dialog